# I can't change binance endpoint version using ccxt

Tags: version, endpoint, binance, ccxt

I am running a bot using CCXT library to operate with Binance Futures API. It was working like a charm so far. However, now I'm getting the following error:

> binance {"code":-5000,"msg":"GET /fapi/v1/positionRisk is retired, please use GET /fapi/v2/positionRisk

I understand the nature of the problem, and I see in the changelog that some endpoints has been deprecated in v1 of endpoints and Binance ask for moving to v2 endpoints:

2023-06-28

Notice:

REST

```
The following endpoints will no longer be supported from 2023-07-15:
    GET /fapi/v1/account
    GET /fapi/v1/balance
    GET /fapi/v1/positionRisk
Please switch to corresponding v2 endpoints:
    GET /fapi/v2/account
    GET /fapi/v2/balance
    GET /fapi/v2/positionRisk
```

I've tried to solve the problem adding a "version" entrance in my Exchange instance:

```
self.ccxt_client = ccxt.binance({'apiKey':API_KEY,
                                        'secret':API_SECRET,
                                        'timeout': 30000,
                                        'enableRateLimit': True,
                                        'ratelimit': 300,
                                        'adjustForTimeDifference': True,
                                        'options':{'defaultType': 'future'},
                                        'version': 'v2'
                                        })
```

According to documentation, this 'v2' string, is attached at the end of the endpoint base name. However the same error appears, as if v1 where still being called.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, after updating CCXT version to the latest, automatically works with Binance v2 API endpoint. It generated new compatibility issues related with pairs nomenclature. EX: BTC/USDT has to be written as "BTC/USDT:USDT" but the original issue was completely solved.